# Abrir aplicación después de instalar con Setup Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Quiero que después de instalar la aplicación esta se abra al completar la instalación. Estoy haciéndolo con C#, gracias

Comment: En estas preguntas de [StackOverflow1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668274/run-exe-after-msi-installation/1681410#1681410)  y [StackOverflow2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168782/visual-studio-installer-how-to-launch-app-at-end-of-installer) encontraras una guia.  Si tienes algun problema con el ingles o esto responde a tu pregunta luego me tomare el tiempo para traducirla y postearla como respuesta

Comment: @Capt.Teach Si lo he mirado, lo que me pasa es que se ejecuta después de instalar pero cuando desinstaló la aplicación esta no se desinstala

Comment: Pero entonces eso ya es otro problema no?. ¿Te sale algún error?¿Compruebas que la ruta del uninstall sea correcta?¿Te has asegurado que el programa se ha cerrado completamente antes de intentar borrarlo?

Comment: @Capt.Teach esta puesto que cuando desinstale se quita, pero el programa sigue como en una especie de temporal

Comment: Dices que cuando des instalas tu programa , aun quedan restos de el en archivos temporales? Puedes comprobar que cada vez que cierras tu programa este borre automaticamente los archivos que va dejando por rollo `TempFile`

Comment: Lo peor es que después de desinstalar el proceso sigue en administrador de tareas

Comment: Pues obviamente no estas controlando bien como cierras tu programa o dejas tareas sin finalizar.

Comment: pero entonces el problema se relaciona a la apertura de la app despues de instalar o es un problema al desinstalar que no quita la entrada que hace iniciar la app al inicio de windows ?

Comment: @Leandro Tuttini después de buscar, encontré que si pones un installer y en la función Commit puedes iniciar el proceso, vale hasta ahí bien, pero cuando desinstalo la aplicación el proceso sigue abierto y no me sale tampoco ningún amigo de que se está ejecutando el proceso al desinstalar. Lo único que quiero es después de instalar el winforms iniciarlo después de instalarlo